# Bitblt,createdibsection, image comes out corrupted

Tags: c++, bitblt, createdibsection

hi im trying to capture screenshot but the image comes out corrupted, can anyone see whats wrong wth the code, basically im trying to use createdibsection so i can accesss the bits directly.

heres what the resulting picture looks
http://oi47.tinypic.com/33c4zko.jpg

```
bool FrameData::Create(int width, int height, ImageFormat imgFormat, HWND sourceWindow)
{
if(width < 0)
    return false;

srcWndDC = GetDC(sourceWindow);
hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(srcWndDC);

if(hdc == nullptr || srcWndDC == nullptr)
{
    return false;
}

memset(&bmpInfo, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height; // top-down
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
switch(imgFormat)
{
case ImageFormat::RGB16:
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 16;
        break;
    case ImageFormat::RGB24:
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
        break;
    case ImageFormat::RGB32:
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
        break;
    default:
        return false;

}
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = height * width * imgFormat;
hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(srcWndDC, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&bits, NULL, NULL);

if(hBitmap == nullptr)
{
    return false;
}

return true;


}

bool FrameData::SaveFrameToFile(std::string& filename)
{
BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHdr = {0};

bmpFileHdr.bfSize=sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
bmpFileHdr.bfType='MB';
bmpFileHdr.bfOffBits=sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

std::ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(filename);

if(!outfile.is_open())
{
    return false;
}


outfile.write((char*)&bmpFileHdr, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
outfile.write((char*)&bmpInfo.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
outfile.write((char*)bits, bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
outfile.close();
return true;
}
```

thats the code, then i just use this to capture the screen

```
 SelectObject(data.GetHDC(), data.GetHBitmap());
 BitBlt(data.GetHDC(),0,0,data.GetWidth(), data.GetHeight(),           data.GetSourceWindowDC(),0,0 , SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't have time to check all the details of your bitmap structures initialization but try `outfile.open(filename, ios_base::out + ios_base::bin);` instead of `outfile.open(filename);`, else all your 0x0A bytes ('\n' or LineFeed) are replaced by 0x0D ('\r' or CarriageReturn) followed by 0x0A (2 bytes MS-DOS/Windows text file end-of-line sequence)!

Also I think that `bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage` should be something like `height * 4 * (((width * bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount) + 0x1F) / 0x20)` (each row of pixels must be 32-bit aligned, resulting in up to 3 unused padding bytes at the end of each row, doesn't matter for RGB32 format).

Comment: +1. If this is what's going on, the file size should be different from what's expected from the pixel count, so that's easy to check.

Comment: Don't forget to count the headers bytes too.